# how to pass a variable to RxJS subscribe()?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have the following code:

```
upload(file) {
  let uploadData = new UploadData();
  this.active_uploads.push(uploadData);
  this.server.get_presigned_post_url().subscribe(url => {
    uploadData.id = extractIdFromUrl(url);
    this.uploader.uploadFile(file, url, () => {
      //success callback
      console.log(uploadData.id + ' done');
    }); 
  });
}
```

The problem is that if i call upload() multiple times in quick succession either,

```
uploadData.id = ...
```

and/or

```
console.log(uploadData.id + ' done');
```

Seems to refer the wrong uploadData instance from a different upload() call.

Why is that?
What is the proper way to handle it?
Can i pass a variable to the subscribe call?

Comment: what is inside the `this.server.get_presigned_post_url()` function? is it create new or subscribe to existing Observable?

Comment: It returns  http.get()

Comment: Well my quess is that when you execute `upload` for the second time, the function inside of `.subscribe` from previous call would be executed one more time with different value. This could happen if Observable returned by `this.server.get_presigned_post_url` is shared across calls

Comment: You can use `.zip` and `Observable.mapTo(var)` and then go from there. But I would better understand if you had a plunkr and a use case.